# How can I extract href links from a within a table th using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a list of all football teams/links from any one of a number of tables within the base URL: *https://fbref.com/en/comps/10/stats/Championship-Stats*

I would then use the link from the href to scrape each individual team's data. The href is embedded within the *th* tag as per below

```
th scope="row" class="left " data-stat="squad"><a href="/en/squads/293cb36b/Barnsley-Stats">Barnsley</a></th

   a href="/en/squads/293cb36b/Barnsley-Stats">Barnsley</a
```

The following code gives me a list of the 'a' tags

```
page = "https://fbref.com/en/comps/10/Championship-Stats"
pageTree = requests.get(page)
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')
Teams = pageSoup.find_all("th", {"class": "left"})
```

Output(for each class of 'left'):

*th class="left" data-stat="squad" scope="row">
a href="/en/squads/293cb36b/Barnsley-Stats">Barnsley,*

I have tried the guidance from a previous Stack question ([Extract links after th in beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48722980/extract-links-after-th-in-beautifulsoup))
However, the following code based on that thread produces errors

*AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_parent'*

```
def import_TeamList():
BASE_URL = "https://fbref.com/en/comps/10/Championship-Stats"
r = requests.get(BASE_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
team_list = []
team_tr = soup.find('a', {'data-stat': 'squad'}).find_parent('tr')
for tr in reels_tr.find_next_siblings('tr'):
    if tr.find('a').text != 'squad':
        break
    midi_list.append(BASE_URL + tr.find('a')['href'])
return TeamList
```

Comment: `return TeamList` - where did you declare `TeamList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version using CSS selectors, which I find simpler than most other methods.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/10/stats/Championship-Stats'
data  = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

links = BeautifulSoup(data).select('th a')
urls = [link['href'] for link in links]
print(urls)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did indeed work.
I made the slight edit of:

urls = [link['href'] for link in links[:24]]

To limit the list to 24 teams. It was duplicating teams as there are more than one table listing the same teams on the website.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from lxml import etree

with requests.Session() as session:
    r = session.get('https://fbref.com/en/comps/10/stats/Championship-Stats')
    r.raise_for_status()
    dom = etree.HTML(str(BS(r.text, 'lxml')))
    for a in dom.xpath('//th[@class="left"]/a'):
        print(a.attrib['href'])
```